# Posso utilizar o "cin" e "getline" em um mesmo código?

Tags: c++

Estava corrigindo o problema de espaços em branco com o `getline` só que me apareceu esse problema onde a pergunta "Digite o nome do funcionário:" é pulada, como resolver isto?

Será que é porque eu estou utilizando `cin` e `getline` em um mesmo programa?Pois só com o `cin << nomeFuncionario;` eu não tenho este problema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
            cout << "\n\nDigite o nome da empresa: ";
            getline (cin,nomeEmpresa);      

            cout << "\n\nNúmero de funcionários: " ;
            cin >> n;

            cout << "\n\nDigite o nome do funcionário: ";
            getline (cin,nomeFuncionario);

            cout << "\n\nDigite o número de horas trabalhadas: ";
            cin >> horasTrabalhadas;
```

Comment: Acho primordial essa leitura para quem está começando em c++ e quer entender um pouco mais sobre entrada e saída de dados. https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programar_em_C%2B%2B/Entrada_e_sa%C3%ADda_de_dados

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Onde tens isto:

```
cout << "\n\nDigite o nome do funcionário: ";
getline (cin,nomeFuncionario);
```

Coloca isto, para executar essa linha enquanto ela não for preenchida.

```
cout << "\n\nDigite o nome do funcionário: ";
while(getline(cin, nomeFuncionario))
  if(nomeFuncionario != ""){
  break;
}
```

A alternância entre `>>` e `getline` deve ser feita com cuidado, pois deve-se seguir à margem os finais de linha de entrada.

Outra opção seria o uso do `ignore` depois da expressão:

```
while (isspace(cin.peek()))
{ 
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Na maior parte das vezes recomenda-se o uso do `ignore` depois do `>>`, para descartar a nova linha, mas dependendo da situação pode descartar também conteúdo não branco. Casos onde a integridade total dos dados recebidos não é de extrema importância.

Answer (score 5):

Depois de utilizar `cin` com o extractor `<<` deve usar-se `cin.ignore(1000,'\n')` para remover o `\n` deixado no *buffer* associado à leitura dos valores introduzidos no teclado (para não ler de forma inadvertida strings vazias nas hipotéticas leituras seguintes).

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int i;
    string nome;

    cout << "Digite um inteiro:";
    cin >> i;
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n'); // Experimente remover esta linha para ver o resultado
    cout << "Digite o seu nome: ";
    getline(cin, nome);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Utilizar o `ignore` é recomendado mas, há vezes que descarta outras coisas também.

Comment: @Edilson Como assim?