# C++ Iterador while pulando a leitura de cin.getline

Tags: c++, loop, while, iterator

Estou iniciando em C++, durante alguns testes notei que após a segunda iteração do while o comando cin.getline não era lido exibindo a linha após ele. Não entendo oq ocorre. Segue o código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    char matter[20] = " ";
    string category(" ");
    ofstream write;
    bool control = true;
    char op = ' ';

    while (control) {
        cout << "Enter matter: ";
        cin.getline(matter, 20);//--------
        write.open("database.txt" , ofstream::app);
        write << "->" << matter << "\n";
        write.close();
        cout << "Prosseguir?[Y/N]:  ";
        cin >> op;
        op = toupper(op);
        if (op == 'N') {
          return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Se alguém souber oq é...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é bem simples, apenas coloque `cin.ignore();` antes do if.

[veja funcioanndo](http://cpp.sh/5tu3e)

Leia o artigo: [C++: Usando o cin.ignore()](http://www.codigomaster.com.br/desenvolvimento/c-usando-o-cin-ignore)

inclusive já tive este mesmo problema no passado [Posso utilizar "cin" e "getline" no mesmo código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/103612/posso-utilizar-o-cin-e-getline-em-um-mesmo-c%C3%B3digo) Veja um pouco da discussão do tópico para entender ainda mais!